# Telerik Scheduler with asp.net - Show Everyones meetings in one display

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, scheduler

I'm working on creating a chart with a list people ("advocates") and their meetings for a particular day, all in a single view.  I'm using Telerik's RadScheduler control (2011 Q2) from their RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX package.

I have a M:M relationship between Advocates and Meetings.  As such, my database tables are named `GRS_Advocate`, `GRS_Meeting`, and `GRS_AdvocateToMeeting`.

What I am trying to accomplish is to have a list of Advocates on the Y-axis and Times (in one-hour increments) on the top of the X-axis.  The closest example on Telerik's website that I can find is http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/timelineview/defaultcs.aspx here, and this is the one I'm trying to mimic with my data.

Here's a visual representation of what I would like:

[image: Desired look of scheduler control]

Now, here's a screengrab of what I'm actually getting:

[image: Actual scheduler control rendered from the code below (included below)]

Those two "Important Meeting" records are for the *same meeting*, with two different Advocates scheduled to attend.  This meeting should be displayed on two different lines, once for each Advocate scheduled to attend, as demonstrated in the first picture.

How do I get to there from here?  I suspect the problem might be within the `<ResourceTypes>` tag I have in the Grid.

Here is the code I've got - I'll share the C# as well although it's likely not as important here.

```
<telerik:RadScheduler runat="server" ID="RadScheduler1" SelectedView="TimelineView"
    DayStartTime="09:00:00" DayEndTime="19:00:00" DataSourceID="EventsDataSource"
    DataKeyField="ID" DataSubjectField="Subject" DataStartField="Start" DataEndField="End"
     OverflowBehavior="Expand"
    Localization-HeaderMultiDay="Work Week" OnNavigationComplete="RadScheduler1_NavigationComplete">
    <AdvancedForm Modal="true" />
    <ResourceTypes>
        <telerik:ResourceType KeyField="Adv_AdvocateID" Name="Advocate" TextField="Adv_FullName" ForeignKeyField="Adv_AdvocateID"
            DataSourceID="AdvocatesDataSource" />
    </ResourceTypes>
    <TimelineView UserSelectable="true" GroupBy="Adv_AdvocateID" GroupingDirection="Horizontal" />
    <MultiDayView UserSelectable="true" />
    <DayView UserSelectable="false" />
    <WeekView UserSelectable="false" />
    <MonthView UserSelectable="false" />
</telerik:RadScheduler>

</asp:Panel>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="EventsDataSource" runat="server"
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GRSConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="select m.[Id], m.[Room], m.[Start], m.[End], m.[Notes], m.[Subject], a.[Adv_AdvocateID], a.[Adv_FullName] from GRS_Meeting m join GRS_AdvocateToMeeting am on am.Meeting = m.Id join GRS_Advocate a on am.advocate = a.Adv_AdvocateID">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="AdvocatesDataSource" runat="server"
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GRSConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT  [Adv_AdvocateID],[Adv_FullName] FROM [GRS_Advocate]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And the C# code, if you're interested:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadScheduler1.SelectedView == SchedulerViewType.TimelineView)
        {
            RadScheduler1.TimelineView.SlotDuration = TimeSpan.Parse(DurationList.SelectedValue);
            RadScheduler1.TimelineView.TimeLabelSpan = int.Parse(TimeLabelSpan.SelectedValue);
            RadScheduler1.TimelineView.ColumnHeaderDateFormat = ColumnHeaderDateFormat.SelectedValue;
            RadScheduler1.TimelineView.NumberOfSlots = int.Parse(NumberOfSlotsList.SelectedValue);
            RadScheduler1.TimelineView.GroupingDirection = (GroupingDirection)Enum.Parse(typeof(GroupingDirection), GroupingDirection.SelectedValue);
        }
        else if (RadScheduler1.SelectedView == SchedulerViewType.MultiDayView)
        {
            RadScheduler1.MultiDayView.NumberOfDays = int.Parse(NumberOfDaysList.SelectedValue);
            RadScheduler1.FirstDayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)int.Parse(FirstDayOfWorkWeekList.SelectedValue);
            RadScheduler1.SelectedDate = RadScheduler1.SelectedDate.AddDays((int)RadScheduler1.FirstDayOfWeek - (int)RadScheduler1.SelectedDate.DayOfWeek);

        }
    }
    protected void RadScheduler1_NavigationComplete(object sender, SchedulerNavigationCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadScheduler1.SelectedView == SchedulerViewType.MultiDayView)
        {

            RadScheduler1.MultiDayView.NumberOfDays = int.Parse(NumberOfDaysList.SelectedValue);
            RadScheduler1.FirstDayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)int.Parse(FirstDayOfWorkWeekList.SelectedValue);

            //SelectedDate adjustment to make a Work Week view from Multi-day view
            int WorkWeekAdjustmentTimeShift = (int)RadScheduler1.FirstDayOfWeek - (int)RadScheduler1.SelectedDate.DayOfWeek;
            if (e.Command == SchedulerNavigationCommand.NavigateToNextPeriod)
            {
                if (WorkWeekAdjustmentTimeShift < 0)
                    WorkWeekAdjustmentTimeShift += 7;

            }
            else if (e.Command == SchedulerNavigationCommand.NavigateToPreviousPeriod)
            {
                if (WorkWeekAdjustmentTimeShift > 0)
                    WorkWeekAdjustmentTimeShift -= 7;
            }
            RadScheduler1.SelectedDate = RadScheduler1.SelectedDate.AddDays(WorkWeekAdjustmentTimeShift);
        }
    }
```

I've been working on this for a while now and I just can't get past this point.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

In the comments it was pointed out that the above image is on Day View, and I should be using Timeline.  That is correct; however, when I view Timeline view my advocates aren't listed.  In fact, there is nothing but a timeline on the x axis with no y axis at all, and no grid to display:

[image: Timeline Scheduler]

Comment: The screenshot you're showing is that of the day view. Shouldn't you be viewing the timeline view if you want it to look like your mock up? I was referencing that example you linked and it seems to resemble what you are looking for, but does not seem to reference "Day View" at all.

Comment: Also, on your line of code: <TimelineView UserSelectable="true" GroupBy="Adv_AdvocateID" GroupingDirection="Horizontal" />. You'd change Grouping direction to "Vertical."

Comment: Thanks KreepN.  I've clarified above, and I have also fixed GroupingDirection to Vertical. please see the update section at the end of the post

Comment: Based on the demo, GroupBy="Adv_AdvocateID" (property in the <timelineview>) should really be GroupBy="Advocate" to match the name you give it in <ResourceTypes>.

Comment: KreepN, THANK YOU!  I can't believe I missed that after looking at it so many times.  Can you please "answer" the question so I can accept it, upvote it, and send you good karma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mimic the Demo at hand you would need to use "Timeline View" which is selectable in the "SelectedView" property of the scheduler itself.

Also, to group by Adv_AdvocateID, you need to always reference the "Name" field you give it in the "ResourceTypes" property field.

-:)

Comment: Thanks, KreepN, for your excellent answer in our first-ever exchange :)

Comment: Lol, if you hang out in the Telerik questions, you're bound to see me more. Glad I could help.